# How to re-index only one product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, indexing

I have added the product using REST API in Magento 2 I want to re-index only one inserted product not fully reindex just one that inserted product.

How to do that ?

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Have you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for reindexing a specific product. You can reindex specific index types (in your case like products). Please check below command for this:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex [indexer]
```

> Where [indexer] is a space-separated list of indexers. Omit [indexer]
> to reindex all indexers.

To view a list of all indexers:

```
bin/magento indexer:info
```

> For detailed info check Magento Official documentation:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html#config-cli-subcommands-index-reindex

Comment: Thanks for the response @Amit 
By programmatically it is also not possible I want to just re-index inside my controller file?

Comment: @Prits, Then this link useful for you: https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-perform-reindexing-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Comment: this will gives me the the array of indexes which is used to perform but it will not work on specific one products. this will run on all the products
I want to re-index just one product programatically.

Comment: @Prits, Sorry for this but I already tell you reindex for specific product is not working. You need to reindex specific indexer type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command for the prodcuts

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product
```

All reindex using below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

When we create a new product or update an existing product then we can reindex using the observer.

1. Create an observer on the 'controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after' event.
2. Create an observer file ProductSaveAfterObserver.php file inside the app/code/Rama/CustomModule/Observer/ directory with the below code

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @category  Rama
 * @package   Rama_CustomModule
 * @author    Rama
 */
namespace Rama\CustomModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry
     */
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * Object intialization
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
    ) {
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Product save after observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            if (!empty($product)) {
                $prodIds = [$product->getId()]; 

                $indexList = [
                    'catalog_category_product',
                    'catalog_product_category',
                    'catalog_product_attribute',
                    'cataloginventory_stock',
                    'inventory',
                    'catalogsearch_fulltext',
                    'catalog_product_price',
                    'catalogrule_product',
                    'catalogrule_rule'
                ];
 
                foreach ($indexList as $index) {
                    $catIndexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get($index);
                
                    if (!$catIndexer->isScheduled()) {
                        $catIndexer->reindexList($prodIds);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2 provides this feature by default when you use Update by Schedule mode. When you make any changes to product it will automatically reindex when the magento default cron is run.**

[image]